# How to create middleware and define in kernel in simple js on mvc

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, babeljs

I want to create middleware and define it in kernel and use it on route request in mvc form

```
class abcd{

    handle(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Time:", new Date())
        next()
    }
}

class abcd{


    handle(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Time:", new Date())
        next()
    }
}
```